# To add a class involving a flag and media query in angular

Tags: html, angular, sass

I want to add class depending on a flag and the screen resolution
I tried

```
[ngClass]="singleFloorFlagStyle ? 'floorPlanContainerWidth' : 'singleFloor'"

 @media only screen and (min-width: 1500){
.floorPlanContainerWidth{
 width: 670px;
 }
}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1400){
.floorPlanContainerWidth{
width: 613px !important;
}
}

.singleFloor{
width: 1300px;
}
```

singleFloorFlagStyle I would receive as true or false.
So singleFloor class gets applied but floorPlanContainerWidth class doesn't.How can I make the media query classes work.

I had referred this [Angular 5: Use ngClass to switch classes for mobile and desktop views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052761/angular-5-use-ngclass-to-switch-classes-for-mobile-and-desktop-views) but I guess my scenario is different

Comment: Is your problem that the class itself is never applied or that the style of the class isn't applied? Because right now you have a "dead range" of 100px between 1400 and 1500 where no style will be applied for the `floorPlanContainerWidth` class.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz The class itself doesn't get applied ,thanks

Comment: .. and you are sure `singleFloorFlagStyle` is true?

Comment: Yeah :) because singleFloor class gets applied, so flag is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added `px` so `floorPlanContainerWidth` not applying

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 1500px){
   .floorPlanContainerWidth{
     width: 670px;
   }
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 1400px){
   .floorPlanContainerWidth{
      width: 613px !important;
   }
 }

.singleFloor{
   width: 1300px;
}
```

Comment: @Enthu it’s no bother

Comment: @Enthu yes, Sure i will try

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[ngClass]="{'floorPlanContainerWidth' : singleFloorFlagStyle , 'singleFloor' : !singleFloorFlagStyle }"
```

If you want to set an initial size of the floorPlanConatainerWidth. So that even if it is not in the media queries ratio then also style will be applied.  Then you have to add the class outside the media queries also and define some width there

```
.floorPlanConatainerWidth{
  // Initially set width without media queries
}

@media ...
```

Comment: No it doesn't resolve, I checked with 1100, 1200, 1230 , diff combinations

Comment: Where your class is present in which file

Comment: Sorry my bad had not used px